# Why does curl sftp fail with "curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK" on one machine but not the other - same host

Tags: curl, ssh, sftp

I have two Raspberry Pies which I use to connect to the same web host. SSH works fine on both machines, but curl SFTP works on one but not the other. How do I fix this?

**Fails here:**

```
pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ ssh me@mydoman.com
Last login: Tue May 11 19:10:06 2021 from node-1759.pool-101-51.dynamic.totinternet.net

pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ curl -T test.txt -u me: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sftp://ftp.mydoman.com/~/public_html/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

The page referred to for help seemed to refer to sslcerts on the host. But, I'm dealing with the same host and presumably the same sslcert. I don't understand.

**Works here:**

```
pi@raspsky:~/webcam$ ssh me@mydoman.com
Last login: Tue May 11 19:16:15 2021 from node-1759.pool-101-51.dynamic.totinternet.net

pi@raspsky:~/webcam$ curl -T test.txt -u me: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sftp://ftp.mydoman.com/~/public_html/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
pi@raspsky:~/webcam$ ssh me@mydoman.com
Last login: Tue May 11 19:16:15 2021 from node-1759.pool-101-51.dynamic.totinternet.net
```

**Addition information and verbose curl output**

```
pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ ssh-keygen -H  -F mydomain.com
# Host mydomain.com found: line 47

pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ curl -v -T test.txt -u me: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sftp://ftp.mydomain.com/~/public_html/
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
*   Trying 192.254.225.101...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x9e78b0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to ftp.mydomain.com (192.254.225.101) port 22 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0* SSH MD5 fingerprint: fb50fba1d4f122aabeeed4d6cd3c99c2
* SSH host check: 2, key: <none>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

---

If I use `mydomain.com` instead of `ftp.mydomain.com` I get a different error:

```
pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ curl -v -T test.txt -u me: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sftp://mydomain.com/~/public_html/
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
*   Trying 192.254.225.101...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x6d78b0)
* Connected to mydomain.com (192.254.225.101) port 22 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* SSH MD5 fingerprint: fb50fba1d4f122aabeeed4d6cd3c99c2
* SSH host check: 0, key: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAvHiEi1H1jbmyADBcrAeq3J+t30T2XbwBqSsjzPghUrJNFbdSyNx+tstlV7VcoEMLdEtKODT8vxBgbu38W6Cirdc0uCshB9STKwULhe66f0NIPY0NGC5EAxOAhX7wVxzPquY4RtWJW7yXcyANvv8ab6mMtzAeIFOLKK6k7j/afDhXnsh6YQLevJ2J3auuU5XdxJUfV3e2/lIRSCe8IWuNY9ohjXfrXglBwo1qlftufujsiFSCfOeEIXJ20OSzvodlCyCzU/YjOrLBLrD9eJvLQovbp39hg7d41K84tsKCXJolTVKQNsWANqEvYw2TuNwW6bLbRlGM3yStSaCWW/WXPw==
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
* Using SSH public key file '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
* Using SSH private key file '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa'
* SSH public key authentication failed: Callback returned error
* Failure connecting to agent
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0* Authentication failure
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (67) Authentication failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `known_hosts` file on the `raspmountain` probably does not contain the hostkey of the server.

You will for sure get more details in curl log.

See also [Why can't curl retrieve the SSH host key (key: )](https://serverfault.com/q/783648/168875)

Answer (score 0):

The failure was the result of the rsa key being in openssh format. When I converted it to rsa format:

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

curl sftp works without error:

pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ curl -v -s -T test.txt -u mike: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sftp://mydomain.com/~/public_html/

- Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x1b378b0)
- Trying 192.254.225.101...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x1b378b0)
- Connected to mydomain.com (192.254.225.101) port 22 (#0)
- SSH MD5 fingerprint: fb50fba1d4f122aabeeed4d6cd3c99c2
- SSH host check: 0, key: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAvHiEi1H1jbmyADBcrAeq3J+t30T2XbwBqSsjzPghUrJNFbdSyNx+tstlV7VcoEMLdEtKODT8vxBgbu38W6Cirdc0uCshB9STKwULhe66f0NIPY0NGC5EAxOAhX7wVxzPquY4RtWJW7yXcyANvv8ab6mMtzAeIFOLKK6k7j/afDhXnsh6YQLevJ2J3auuU5XdxJUfV3e2/lIRSCe8IWuNY9ohjXfrXglBwo1qlftufujsiFSCfOeEIXJ20OSzvodlCyCzU/YjOrLBLrD9eJvLQovbp39hg7d41K84tsKCXJolTVKQNsWANqEvYw2TuNwW6bLbRlGM3yStSaCWW/WXPw==
- SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
- Using SSH public key file '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
- Using SSH private key file '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa'
- Initialized SSH public key authentication
- Authentication complete
- Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x1b378b0)
- Connection #0 to host mydomain.com left intact